# How can I change the cursor that shows when you type without replacing it? (beam_r.cur)

Tags: windows-registry, mouse-cursor

I have found that most paths to cursors are stored in `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Control Panel\Cursors\Default`, but there is no registry value for changing beam_r.cur that I could find. How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are asking about this :

[image]

The registry entry exists under your registry key and is called
`IBeam`.
However, for some reason this registry entry doesn't have a value,
so it's unknown whether it can be set to a value and what effect
this will have.

The cursor file itself is found at `C:\Windows\Cursors\beam_r.cur`.

Comment: I have found that the registry values don't actually correspond to what mouse cursor file is currently used.